# How to create a generic buffer in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, buffer, typed-arrays

I have the following class:

```
export class BufferData {
  arr: Float32Array;
  index: number;

  constructor() {
    this.arr = new Float32Array(8);
    this.index = 0;
  }

  maybeResize() {
    let curArr = this.arr;

    if (this.index < curArr.length) {
      return;
    }

    let newArr = new Float32Array(curArr.length * 2);

    for (let i = 0; i < curArr.length; i++) {
      newArr[i] = curArr[i];
    }

    this.arr = newArr;
  }

  push(val: number) {
    this.maybeResize();

    this.arr[this.index++] = val;
  }
}
```

This works, but I would like to make it generic if possible. That is, I'd like the signature of the class to be something like:

```
export class BufferData<T extends TypedArray>
```

Such that all instances of `Float32Array` in the above code would be replaced with `T` and I would be able to create one like this:

```
let buffer = new BufferData<Float32Array>();
```

However, I could not find whether or not `Float32Array` had a parent. Also, when I tried to do something like:

```
this.arr = new T(8);
```

in the constructor, it told me `T` was a type and not a value.

Is this sort of thing possible? Or do I have to just duplicate the class for each concrete type I wish to use it with?

Comment: Afraid not. But you could use `new BufferData(Float32Array)` instead where you pass the typed array instead. Is this ok for you? If it is I'll expand it into an answer.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean? `Float32Array` is referenced in both `maybeResize` and the constructor. How would `maybeResize` work if you passed the type to the constructor?

Comment: On my main now. I was trying to say that with `new BufferData<Float32Array>()`, there would be no way to actually instantiate the typed array of the correct type. However, if you use `new BufferData(Float32Array)`, you can get BOTH the type AND the correct typed array as a value that you can instantiate later.

Comment: Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLl1Am)?

Comment: Oh cool, yeah if something like that works and is the best way of doing this feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it